# Add post tags to previously created custom post type

Tags: posts, tags, customization

I am trying to add post tags to the custom post types bbpress creates, so that I can do some "related topics" kind of stuff.

Is there a function that adds a post support like `'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')`, but to a post type that was previously created?

My thought was I could just re create the custom post type on theme install or soemthing and hope it didnt mess anything up, but I really wanted to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) to add existing taxonomies to existing post types:

```
function wpa_tags_for_cpt(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'post_type_name' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_tags_for_cpt', 999 );
```